# Vue-Cli: 'title' option for htmlWebpackPlugin does not work

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm using vue-cli (3.4.1) and I'm trying to simply change the title of the document.

I added the following to the vue.config.js

```js
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config
          .plugin('html')
          .tap((args) => {
            args[0].title = 'Custom Title';
            return args;
          });
      },
```

and inspected the webpack config with `vue inspect --plugin html` resulting in the following output

```js
    /* config.plugin('html') */
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
      {
        templateParameters: function () { /* omitted long function */ },
        template: '<path>\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-service\\lib\\config\\index-default.html',
        title: 'Custom Title'
      }
    )
```

The title of the Webapp still says "Vue App".

Any ideas why?

PS: I do not want to set `document.title = 'Custom Title'` somewhere in my app. I want the title between the `<title>`-tags in the `<head>` element of the document to be altered at build time.

Comment: That could be a bug. I recommend [reporting it](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I submitted a bug report as recommended by @tony19.

tldnr: Edit the title in the template at `public/index.html` which will be used at build time.

Long version: I did not have the `public/index.html` anymore in my project, apparently I deleted it some time ago and therefore never used the template functionality.
The cli still used a template located somewhere and therefore all changes for the htmlWebpackPlugin do nothing.

So either you disable the index.html-template and modify the htmlWebpackPlugin or you edit the template to make your changes.

Answer (score 59):

Unfortunately the above answers didn't help me.
As stated [in the offical documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin) you only need to add the `vue.config.js` to your root folder and add the following:

```js
    // vue.config.js
    module.exports = {
      chainWebpack: config => {
        config
        .plugin('html')
        .tap(args => {
          args[0].title = 'Your new title'
          return args
        })
      }
    }
```

Keep in mind that you have to stop the App and start again with `npm run serve`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 34):

According to the [configuration reference of the Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages), you could set the title by overriding the pages section in `vue.config.js`. Since all config options are optional except for entry, this should do it:

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/index/main.js',
      title: 'Custom Title'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me! I only needed to modify the `entry` path to how my entry file is setup.

Comment: This worked fine also for me. I simply had to restart my docker container.

Comment: This is the simplest way to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 16):

To set the title of a vue-cli application you can set the title in HtmlWebpackPlugin (just as you have)

```js
/* vue.config.js */
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap((args) => {
        args[0].title = 'Custom Title';
        return args;
      });
  },
```

then you must edit the `<title>` of `public/index.html` to reference the title using lodash syntax.

```html
<!-- public/index.html -->
<head>
  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
```

Check out Html Webpack Plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) on writing your own templates!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I could not make changing the title from the webpack-config work, i'm assuming vue-cli overrides the one from the config later. What worked for me is setting `VUE_APP_TITLE=<custom title>` in `.env` and using `<title><%= process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE %></title>` in `index.html`. [Source](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title used by the HtmlWebpackPlugin by setting the "name" property in package.json in the root of your vue-cli app. No need for chainWebpack just to change the title.

Comment: This does work, but the package.json name is restricted to `lower-case_hypens-and-underscores` only.